# PDF generation with Japanese fonts in Codeigniter using TCPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf, cjk

I am facing problem to generate japanese text based pdf using TCPDF. Previously I was working in raw php, html and css and tcpdf was working just fine with the following code:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    if (@file_exists(APPPATH . 'libraries/tcpdf/examples/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/tcpdf/examples/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }
    if (@file_exists(APPPATH . 'libraries/tcpdf/examples/lang/jpn.php')) {
        require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/tcpdf/examples/lang/jpn.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

    $pdf->SetFont('cid0jp', '', 11);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Output('result.pdf', 'I');
```

which can generate my desired pdf with japanese text.

**氏名
(全角・名字と名前の間に字スペー
ス)
Name
(Last Name/First name)**

But when I tried to include this in codeigniter controller, the japanese texts are showing question marks in the generated pdf:

```
require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

The pdf output becomes like the following:

**??
(?????????????????)
Name
(Last Name/First name)**

What I am missing? Can anybody give me a solution? I will greatly appreciate a help here.

Comment: My guess is that you're missing a Japanese font. You must have a `.ttf` that you can import using `->setFont()` and `->addFont()` see my duplicate for more information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FPDF: Russian text is not outputted properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961452/fpdf-russian-text-is-not-outputted-properly)

Comment: same thing is working in my raw code perfectly. I just used the tcpdf as library in codeigniter just like other pluging. the pdf is generating, but the issue is japanese texts are not showing, rather question marks.
The russian font problem is irrevelent to what am I asking

Comment: In that case I think the issue may be that you're using the `->writeHTML` function. Try outputting some Japanese text with `$pdf->setXY(50,50); $pdf->Cell(0,0,'text here');`

Comment: You are right. The japanese texts are showing if I write $pdf->Cell(0,0,'氏名 (全角・名字と名前の間に字スペー ス) Name (Last Name/First name)'); like you suggested. 
So the problem is in writeHTML() function! How can I solve it? 
The html document which I want to generate as pdf is very large.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you're going to like my solution.. I think you have no other option but to `->writeHTML()` and then use the `->setXY()` and `->Cell` functions to output the text. Failing that, generating the text as an image using something like [imagestring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) and then including it in the HTML may save you some time, or create more headaches. FPDF is a very old library and I couldn't find anything on your issue during my initial research.

Comment: yes, i dislike the solution actually. :p I will try to debug some more in the writeHtml function to find the root problem. but I may go for your solution tomorrow if no easy solution revealed.

Comment: is there any other opensource pdf library in php available which can be used in codeigniter and generate CJK based pdf? I have tried to use dompdf previously but it shows much poorer representation in pdf, can't show cjk texts also.

Comment: From my experience, HTML -> PDF generation is pretty difficult. At work we use PrinceXML but it comes with quite a hefty license cost and it's closed. FDPF is probably your second best PDF generator for PHP (simply because of how long it has been around for). Apart from those 2 I really don't know. Sorry I can't be of any more help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try any one from listed (because I'm not sure which one works for you):-
1) `$pdf->SetFont('kozgopromedium', '', 11);`
2) `$pdf->SetFont('kozminproregular', '', 11);`
3) `$pdf->SetFont('cid0jp', '', 11);`
4) `$pdf->SetFont('arialunicid0', '', 11);`
5) `$pdf->SetFont('arialuni', '', 12);`

If you have font file(.ttf) in your system, then you can give path also like :-
`$pdf->addTTFfont('path/myfont.ttf', '', '', 11);`

Comment: 'cid0jp' suppose to work, as it is working in my raw code, but not in codeigniter framework after using tcpdf as a library.  :(

Comment: I suspect the problem lies somewhere in the library integration process for codeigniter, but can't figure out where.

Comment: @SabbirRupom You should check your error logs, if the font `cid0jp` isn't accessible by FPDF then it'll be throwing errors.

Comment: @Yash Parekh, I cant find the addTTFfont function from pdf object, but can find the $pdf->AddFont($family, $style, $fontfile, $subset) function. I am trying to set the parameters in the function.

Comment: @isThisJavascript, can't find any error regarding this in log. I am using Xampp.

Comment: @SabbirRupom I wrote that before we got confirmation that the font actually works in regards to your comment made on the OP. Therefore, this solution that Yash Parekh provides is incorrect, as the font is already installed.

Comment: It's working for me. I am using Codeigniter.